# SSIS deployment yields Error 27123

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

An attempted deployment from (localhost) to (remote server) yielded the Error 27123 which, appears to be a credentials-related issue. After spending several hours the resolution appears to be one of assigning local-to-the-remote server Windows credentials that are used to launch DTEexec.exe. I am using VS2012 Ultimate locally with SQL Server 2014 Developer version and remote SQL version 2012 SP1. However, my attempts have failed so far.

I would VERY much like to be able to deploy to the remote server inside of VS2012, including creating folders, etc but am still at a loss as to the missing piece needed.

We do not have Active Directory set up as the remote is on the Amazon S3 cloud bit other than that is pretty much a plain vanilla setup. I also noted some folks suggested a Kerberos-based response but before I ask our network guru to proceed I'd like at least to get confirmation.

I AM able to manually FTP, install and run packages when remoted in but that stinks for my contractor who I would also like to be able to have me out of his way. *s*

All found online materials have not yet yielded the one last piece. I suspect my ignorance rather than the lack of a real solution and would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Backward compatibility is not a feature, are you certain you're developing SSIS packages locally using 2014 and deploying remotely to a 2012 instance?

Comment: billinkc, 

Yep, local is SQL 2014 and VS2012, remote is SQL 2012 and the same package. I've found that the VS version is what is important. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm hoping to get back to this in the next day or two - when I get free time. *chuckle*